# How to create new threads per function call in c

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to implement a shuffling technique based on a random time so that it is possible for one message to overtake the next message and becomes shuffled. I have an original message that is separated into chunks per thread. Each thread sleeps and prints out the chunk afterwards.

original_message > grab a slice of original_message > deal with it in another thread > grab another slice > deal with it in another NEW thread while the other thread may/may not be running > and repeat until all slice is taken.

However, sometimes the output is the same and that they do not output the after the sleep one by one e.g. the one with 0 seconds sleep comes out first.... How can I create a new thread with its own stack so that it does not share those variables. I'm not sure mutex lock will suffice because it may affect the sleep timings. What can I do to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
struct argsparam {
    int sleep;
    char split_message[5];
};

void* sleep_shuffle(void *arguments){
    struct argsparam *args = arguments;
    sleep(args->sleep);
    printf("shuffled message: %s\n", args->split_message);
}

int main(){
    struct argsparam args;
    pthread_t sleeppt[4];
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    char original_message[20] = "1234567890abcdefghij"; 

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        memcpy(args.split_message , original_message+(i*5), 5);
        args.split_message[5] = '\0'; //null terminator
        args.sleep = rand() % 5;

        printf("message: %s and time: %d\n", args.split_message, args.sleep);
        if(pthread_create( &sleeppt[i], NULL, sleep_shuffle, (void *)&args) != 0)
            printf("Error in creating thread!");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        pthread_join(sleeppt[i], NULL);
    }

}
```

Comment: the thread function should end with something similar to: `pthread_exit( NULL );`  Otherwise the compiler will output: `Warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`

Comment: regarding: `char original_message[20] = "1234567890abcdefghij";`  the message is actually 21 bytes (remember the NUL byte at the end)

Comment: the function: `sleep()` is expecting a `unsigned int`, not an `int`

Comment: in C, the index into an array is from 0 to (one less than the length of the array).  So the `split_message[5]` array has valid indexes from 0 to 4.  This line: `args.split_message[5] = '\0';` is writing past the upper bounds of the array.  That is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the thread function(s) are all pointing to the same argument struct.  So the actual values read from the struct will depend on which thread is executing and how that relates to where in the `main()` function the code is executing.

Comment: regarding: `srand((unsigned) time(&t));`   For this line to pass a value to `srand()`, the parameter to `time()` should be NULL. So the declaration of the variable `t` can be eliminated

Comment: regarding: `args.sleep = rand() % 5;`  there is no guarantee that the results of this statement will be the set: `0,1,2,3,4`.   Suggest using the loop counter `i` being assigned to `args.sleep`

Comment: @user3629249 thank you for the code review, they were all duly noted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing the same copy of `args` to each thread, overwriting the previous value before calling the next thread, so what each thread reads is dependent on the timing of each thread.

Create an array of `struct argsparam`, one for each thread, then pass in the pointer to the appropriate instance.  That way they won't interfere with each other.

```
int main(){
    // an array of args
    struct argsparam args[4];
    pthread_t sleeppt[4];
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    char original_message[20] = "1234567890abcdefghij";

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        // assign to a specific array instance for each thread
        memcpy(args[i].split_message , original_message+(i*5), 5);
        args[i].split_message[5] = '\0'; //null terminator
        args[i].sleep = rand() % 5;

        printf("message: %s and time: %d\n", args[i].split_message, args[i].sleep);
        if(pthread_create( &sleeppt[i], NULL, sleep_shuffle, (void *)&args[i]) != 0)
            printf("Error in creating thread!");
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        pthread_join(sleeppt[i], NULL);
    }

}
```

Sample output (yours may vary):

```
message: 12345 and time: 0
message: 67890 and time: 3
message: abcde and time: 2
message: fghij and time: 1
shuffled message: 12345
shuffled message: fghij
shuffled message: abcde
shuffled message: 67890
```

Also, your `split_message` array isn't big enough to hold the string you're copying in.  You need a total of 6 bytes, for for each of 5 characters and one for the null terminator.

```
struct argsparam {
    int sleep;
    char split_message[6];
};
```

You're "lucky" that you're not stepping on memory you shouldn't due to structure padding.

Comment: of course, that makes sense! argh, why didn't i think of that!

Answer (score 1):

First, the size of the "split_message[5] of struct argsparam" array is incorrect.

Second, why not use "args" as an array?

```
--- orig.c  2017-06-14 03:18:25.569775282 +0900
+++ dest.c  2017-06-14 03:16:52.989777492 +0900
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@

 struct argsparam {
    int sleep;
-   char split_message[5];
+   char split_message[6];
 };

 void* sleep_shuffle(void *arguments){
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@ void* sleep_shuffle(void *arguments){
 }

 int main(){
-   struct argsparam args;
+   struct argsparam args[4];
    pthread_t sleeppt[4];
    time_t t;
    int i;
@@ -25,12 +25,12 @@ int main(){
    char original_message[20] = "1234567890abcdefghij"; 

    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
-       memcpy(args.split_message , original_message+(i*5), 5);
-       args.split_message[5] = '\0'; //null terminator
-       args.sleep = rand() % 5;
+       memcpy(args[i].split_message , original_message+(i*5), 5);
+       args[i].split_message[5] = '\0'; //null terminator
+       args[i].sleep = rand() % 5;

-       printf("message: %s and time: %d\n", args.split_message, args.sleep);
-       if(pthread_create( &sleeppt[i], NULL, sleep_shuffle, (void *)&args) != 0)
+       printf("message: %s and time: %d\n", args[i].split_message, args[i].sleep);
+       if(pthread_create( &sleeppt[i], NULL, sleep_shuffle, (void *)(args + i)) != 0)
            printf("Error in creating thread!");
    }
```